# mysql_fetch_array -> 2 mysql queries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables: customers and customer_ids
With functions mysql_fetch_array() and while() I created a table containing all the customers from customers table. How can I get customer id for each customer from customer_ids?

Let's imagine that I have following mysql tables

```
customers:
id    identify      name
1     UK10-00021    Robert's Market
2     UK10-00381    Tom's Market
3     SE30-00001    Sam's Market
...
```

```
customer_ids:
id    customer_identify    type     customer_id
1     SE30-00001           10       113472
2     SE30-00001           20       42718  
3     UK10-00381           10       110390
4     UK10-00021           10       100031
...
```

and I need to create following html table with php

```
Customer id         Customer name
------------------------------------------------------
100031              Robert's Market
113472              Sam's Market
110390              Tom's Market
...
```

Comment: Learn more about `JOIN` queries.

Comment: Learn more about normalization.  There is no clear reason these are in two separate tables.  Then no JOIN would be needed.

Comment: @Misunderstood In this case, one customer can have any number of `customer_id`s. That's why I have two separated tables. Is that ok or is there some easier way to do this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one function, run a join in your query

```
SELECT customer_id, name FROM customer_ids 
INNER JOIN customers ON customer_ids.customer_identify = customers.identify
```

This should get the required fields then jun run your loop normally

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JOIN` operation

```
 select a.coustomer_id ,b.name from customer_ids a 
       LEFT JOIN customers b 
       on a.customer_identify=b.identify
```